# Streamlit reset results on input change

Tags: python, button, onchange, reset, streamlit

My problem is very similar to the url below:
https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/the-button-inside-a-button-seems-to-reset-the-whole-app-why/1051

I have a button that will load sliders and inputs depending on a certain value that users enter. The idea is that whenever I change the slider, or do a change on the input, the page reset results.

The solution described on the url will not work. It will give the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'SessionState' has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using streamlit 0.65 you needed to fix SessionState.py (at least the version that I have):

### works in streamlit 0.64 (line 87)

```
(not hasattr(s, '_main_dg') and s.enqueue == ctx.enqueue)
```

### works in streamlit 0.65 (notice the *_enqueue*)

```
(not hasattr(s, '_main_dg') and s.enqueue == ctx._enqueue)
```

Comment: As a side note, I switched over to using the query params to store application state.  See the documentation on `st.experimental_get_query_params()` and `st.experimental_set_query_params()`.  It is more native of storing application state.